# Alarm Manager events not fired (registering for notifications per day)

Tags: android

I am writing an application which needs a homewidget showing the current date. For that I have used the alarm manager registering as follows:-

```
Intent intent = new Intent(HomeScreenWidgetProvider.ACTION_UPDATE_DATE);
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_IDS, appWidgetId);
    intent.setData(getUriData(appWidgetId));
    PendingIntent datePendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

    AlarmManager alarms = (AlarmManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    alarms.cancel(datePendingIntent);
    **alarms.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, getTimeForMidnight(), AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, datePendingIntent);**
```

As you see, the above code registers for notifications first for the next 12.00AM with an interval of a day from there on. I update the date in my widget when I get a notification from alarm manager.

There is one big problem though. I don't get the alarm manager events when the date changes (at 12.00AM). And so the date does not change in my home screen widget.

The above code works fine in the emulator but not on the device. I am using Samsung Galaxy S 19000 for (real time) testing.

Is there a problem with use of alarm manager? Or is there an alternate way of receiving date change notifications?

Answer (score 0):

I think in `setRepeating()` method, you should set the first parameter as `AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP`. If you use `AlarmManager.RTC`, the alarm event won't be triggered when the device is asleep. Please see the SDK document about AlarmManager for more details.

Also, you can register a BroadcastReciever listening to `ACTION_DATE_CHANGED`, by which you can receive date change event.
Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But I don't get an event even when the phone is not asleep. Yesterday I read online that there is a firmware defect in Samsung Galaxy S. Alos, I have registered for ACTION_DATE_CHANGED but that is an event when you change the date manually. And it is not fired if you set the date backwards. 

Anybody aware of such a defect? Or is there something that can be done to make it working?